# Woocommerce: Disable login requirement for appointment cancelation URL adress [wp nonce]

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, nonce

I am using woocommerce + plugin for appointments calendar. People can book their appointment right from the product and create a purchase.

If they want to cancel this appointment they can do it from my-account area by clicking at cancel button.

Cancelation URL adress slug is generated by system and it looks like this:

```
/?cancel_appointment=true&appointment_id=442&redirect&_wpnonce=c328e0bab6
```

When you are logged out it does not work and when you are logged in your appointment will change status to canceled.

What I need to do is to change the requirement of the URL authorization so when you are logged out it will let you cancel the appointment because here is creating of accounts really annoying for the customers.

This is a part of the code I have found in files of the plugin. Maybe it should help.

```
/**
 * Returns the cancel URL for an appointment
 *
 * @param string $redirect
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function get_cancel_url( $redirect = '' ) {
    $cancel_page = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( '' ) );

    if ( ! $cancel_page ) {
        $cancel_page = home_url();
    }

    return apply_filters(
        'appointments_cancel_appointment_url',
        wp_nonce_url(
            add_query_arg(
                array(
                    'cancel_appointment' => 'true',
                    'appointment_id'     => $this->get_id(),
                    'redirect'           => $redirect,
                ),
                $cancel_page
            ),
            'woocommerce-appointments-cancel_appointment'
        ),
        $this
    );
}
```

Another code I have found is here

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

/**
* Handle frontend forms
*/
class WC_Appointment_Form_Handler {

/**
 * Hook in methods
 */
public static function init() {
    add_action( 'init', array( __CLASS__, 'cancel_appointment' ), 20 );
}

/**
 * Cancel an appointment.
 */
public static function cancel_appointment() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['cancel_appointment'] ) && isset( 
 $_GET['appointment_id'] ) ) {

        $appointment_id         = absint( $_GET['appointment_id'] );
        $appointment            = get_wc_appointment( $appointment_id );
        $appointment_can_cancel = $appointment->has_status( get_wc_appointment_statuses( 'cancel' ) );
        $redirect               = $_GET['redirect'];
        $is_wc_appointment      = is_a( $appointment, 'WC_Appointment' ) ? true : false;

        if ( $appointment->has_status( 'cancelled' ) ) {
            // Message: Already cancelled - take no action.
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Your appointment has already been cancelled.', 'woocommerce-appointments' ), 'notice' );

        } elseif ( $is_wc_appointment && $appointment_can_cancel && $appointment->get_id() == $appointment_id && isset( $_GET['_wpnonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['_wpnonce'], 'woocommerce-appointments-cancel_appointment' ) ) {
            // Cancel the appointment
            $appointment->update_status( 'cancelled' );
            WC_Cache_Helper::get_transient_version( 'appointments', true );

            // Message.
            wc_add_notice( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_appointment_cancelled_notice', __( 'Your appointment has been cancelled.', 'woocommerce-appointments' ) ), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_appointment_cancelled_notice_type', 'notice' ) );

            do_action( 'woocommerce_appointments_cancelled_appointment', $appointment->get_id() );
        } elseif ( ! $appointment_can_cancel ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Your appointment can no longer be cancelled. Please contact us if you need assistance.', 'woocommerce-appointments' ), 'error' );
        } else {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Invalid appointment.', 'woocommerce-appointments' ), 'error' );
        }

        if ( $redirect ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( $redirect );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
}

WC_Appointment_Form_Handler::init();
```

If you need anything else from the code I may search for it. Because this is the first time I am facing the problem like this.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by code edit from

```
elseif ( $is_wc_appointment && $appointment_can_cancel && $appointment->get_id() == $appointment_id && isset( $_GET['_wpnonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['_wpnonce'], 'woocommerce-appointments-cancel_appointment' ) ) {
```

to

```
elseif ( $is_wc_appointment && $appointment_can_cancel && $appointment->get_id() == $appointment_id) {
```